# Build xCode project for xCode 3.2.5 and xCode 4.3.2 with NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore class

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I've my iPhone project on the xCode 4.3.2 and it works well. It uses NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore class and it's base SDK is iOS 5.0.
Now I am going to build my project on the xCode 3.2.5 and it says error "Undefined symbol NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore".
Of course, I know NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore class is supported from iOS 5.0 and xCode 3.2.5 didn't supported iOS 5.0.
So I want to disable these features older the iOS 5.0, and enable over the iOS 5.0.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the code which makes use of features that were introduced with the 5.0 SDK like so:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 50000
    // Code using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore goes here
#endif
```

Note that this is conditional compilation.  The test is performed when building, not when running.  So, if you build in an older version of Xcode without the 5.0 SDK, then the resulting program will *never* use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, no matter where you run it.  There is no feasible way to build against an older SDK and yet still use feature of the newer SDK if they're available at runtime.

Edited to add: see Apple's [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer. It is just what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to weak link the the framework that contain the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` class.
Then in you code do something like things:

```
if ([NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore class]) {
    // Class wil return non nil uf the class exists.
   NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore new];
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't compile if building against an SDK that doesn't even have `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` declared.  It only works if you compile against an SDK that knows that symbol but set a deployment target that predates it.

Comment: True, you will need to set the iOS deployment target lower.

Comment: No. The point is he's building against an SDK that doesn't know about `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` at all.  What you wrote just won't build under those circumstances, regardless.  The technique you outline helps for a different scenario: when he's building against a new enough SDK but wants to deploy to earlier OSes.